# How to create bmi calculator inside flash cs5.5 using actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

I'm not very familiar with flash so this is my current problem to deal with. I've found some code but it's in `actionscript 2.0`, when i tried to run it in my project, it shows the following error.

Here are my errors:
1. Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 6

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type flash.text:TextField.

2. Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 8

> 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method on.

3. Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 8

> 1120: Access of undefined property release.

```
var weight_BMI;
var height_BMI;
var BMI_FINAL; 
total_BMI=Number(weight_BMI.text)/(Number(height_BMI.text)*Number(height_BMI.text));

on(release){
    trace(weight_BMI.text)
    trace(height_BMI.text)
    trace(BMI_FINAL)
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried along with the error?

Comment: @Smittey hi, i've edited the question with my code and error..

Comment: AS2 is so completely different to AS3 in that AS3 you need to think in terms of functions. The style of programming is very similar to that of Java, so the code above won't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AS2` is very different from `AS3`. `AS3` works by using methods (in the same way as `Java`, for example). See the code below as an example (note, you may need to edit/rename your fields to get it to compile)

It works by attaching a `Click EventListener` to your calculate button which when triggered it runs the `calculateBMI` method. This method then performs the calculation and prints the result to your text field.

```
var myBmi:TextField;
var total_BMI:Number;    

function calculateBMI(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    total_BMI = Number(weight_BMI.text)/(Number(height_BMI.text)*Number(height_BMI.text));  
    myBmi.text = String(total_BMI);
}

btnCalculate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, calculateBMI);
```

Comment: i can run my work with the code that you give but i cannot insert the value. can you teach me how?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert the value"?

Comment: When i run the code, it only show the interface. i cannot insert the weight and height value in it. T_T

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. The code I provided assumes that you have 3 text fields created on the stage called `weight_BMI`, `height_BMI` and `myBmi`. The numbers entered into `weight_BMI` and `height_BMI` are used for the calculation and then outputted to the `myBmi` text field.

Comment: I have all three textfields for weight_BMI, height_BMI and myBmi text field, but it appears the error of Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 8 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type String.

Comment: It probably has something to do with how you've formatted your text box. It's basically saying that it's expecting a string, but it got a number back. Try changing the line `myBmi.text = total_BMI;` to `myBmi.text = String(total_BMI);`

Comment: i put everything inside but still i cannot insert any value so can you take a look at my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3as0z0qgu5vhol/Untitled-1.fla?dl=0

Comment: I don't have flash installed on this machine. I'll try my best to help you on here though. Did you change what I told you to change? What's the result?

Comment: just change text type from "Dynamic text" into " Input text"

Comment: i have change based on your instruction, when i press control+enter the ouput show me the weight box,height box and total bmi box but i cannot insert any value into the box. that is my problem now.

Comment: did you change the type of "weight_BMI" , "height_BMI" into Input text

Comment: @kare81 thank youuuu!! finally my problem is solved!! :D

Comment: @Smittey thank youuu to you tooo!! my bmi calculator is actually working now!! :)